# Exclude main image from Magento product gallery

Tags: magento

I need to update my database of products to mark the "base" image of every product as Excluded. Some products have 1 image, some have more than 1. In each case one image is marked as being the Base, Small and Thumb image. In every case, where an image is marked as such, I need it to be excluded from the gallery.

Currently, without it being excluded, that image will show up twice in the lightbox gallery (Magento 1.4.0.1).

Does someone know the database structure well enough to give me a mySQL solution to update this?

I can manage future new products easily enough, but there's no way I'm running through 22000 products manually! :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL to do this in Magento 1.4.0.1 is:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
SET Disabled = 1
WHERE Position = 1
```

I agree that updating the gallery code would have been a good/better solution, but in my case I am easily able to keep on top of this as new products are added in future.

Comment: I have also modified my image import script so that it now excludes the image being imported from the gallery. It only imports one image per product (my script) so this works spot on for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to update your gallery code to exclude the first image you also do not have an ongoing need to update the product images.